# React is it possible to receive onSubmit event in child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a form and each of the form items (I call Cards) are inside of a child components. My submit button is in the parent component of the form items, and when I click submit, I want to to pass the event handler into the child component, may I know is there a way to  do it?

I have some code snippeet here to show you guys what I have done, thanks !

```
// Parent Component
  const card = cardsList.map(el => {
    return (
      <div className="card-holder" key={decodeHtml(el.question)}>
        <Card 
          id="question1"
          question={decodeHtml(el.question)}
          answer={el.correct_answer}
          incorrectAnswers={el.incorrect_answers}
          handleSubmit={handleSubmit}
        />
      </div>
    )
  })

  function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(event)
  }

  return (
    <form className="game" style={style} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      {card}

      <input type="submit" value="Submit" className="submit-btn" />
    </form>
  )
}
```

Thank you!

```
// Child Component
import React from "react"
import {shuffle, decodeHtml} from "/src/script/Helper.js"


function Card(props) {

  const [arr, setArr] = React.useState(shuffle([0,1,2,3]));

  const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState(false)


  function toggleCheck(event) {
    setChecked(prevChecked => {
      return event.target.id
    })
  }

  return (
    <div className="card">
      <h4 className="card--question">{props.question}</h4>
      <div className="card--answers">
        <div className="card--answer">
          <input 
            type="radio" 
            name={props.question} 
            id={`${props.question} ans1`}
            onChange={toggleCheck}
            checked={checked === `${props.question} ans1`}
            correct={arr[0] === 3 ? "true" : "false"}
          />
          <label htmlFor={`${props.question} ans1` }>{arr[0] === 3 ? decodeHtml(props.answer) : decodeHtml(props.incorrectAnswers[arr[0]])}</label>
        </div>

        <div className="card--answer">
          <input 
            type="radio" 
            name={props.question} 
            id={`${props.question} ans2`} 
            onChange={toggleCheck}
            checked={checked === `${props.question} ans2`}
            correct={arr[1] === 3 ? "true" : "false"}
          />
          <label htmlFor={`${props.question} ans2`}>{arr[1] === 3 ? decodeHtml(props.answer) : decodeHtml(props.incorrectAnswers[arr[1]])}</label>
        </div>

        <div className="card--answer">
          <input 
            type="radio" 
            name={props.question} 
            id={`${props.question} ans3`} 
            onChange={toggleCheck}
            checked={checked === `${props.question} ans3`}
            correct={arr[2] === 3 ? "true" : "false"}
          />
          <label htmlFor={`${props.question} ans3`}>{arr[2] === 3 ? decodeHtml(props.answer) : decodeHtml(props.incorrectAnswers[arr[2]])}</label>
        </div>

        <div className="card--answer">
          <input 
            type="radio" 
            name={props.question} 
            id={`${props.question} ans4`} 
            onChange={toggleCheck}
            checked={checked === `${props.question} ans4`}
            correct={arr[3] === 3 ? "true" : "false"}
          />
          <label htmlFor={`${props.question} ans4`}>{arr[3] === 3 ? decodeHtml(props.answer) : decodeHtml(props.incorrectAnswers[arr[3]])}</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Card;
```

Comment: Why do you need to do so? Would you tell me what your purpose is for this?

Comment: @TheKNVB i wanted the card itself to manage the state instead of the parent,

Comment: What event handler do you want to pass?